# How to use JQuery Mobile in a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, dry

What does your routes.rb file look like?

How do you handle mobile vs. web routes? Do you define some sort of namespace?

Should one have a mysite.com/mobile directory? What would be the DRY approach to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this can get you on the right track:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices

Comment: According to the Railscast, it looks like I will have to replicate all of my views and modify them to use JQuery-Mobile. These new views will have a .mobile.erb file extension. I'll also have to configure a mobile MIME type. All in all, it doesn't seem like too much coding. Thanks for your prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need extra views - just put a bunch of `<% if mobile? %>` into your existing ones.

Inspired by http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/02/23/a-better-way-to-add-mobile-pages-to-a-rails-site/, I added this to my `application_controller.rb`:

```
def mobile?
  if session[:mobile_override]
    session[:mobile_override] == "1"
  else
    request.user_agent.downcase =~ /mobile|android|touch|webos|hpwos/
  end
end
helper_method :mobile?
```

The same article also goes to show why using custom domains/routes for mobile is a bad idea.